# How do I use pandas to make pairing of rows based on values from multiple columns and update counts for pairings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a data frame that looks like this. In this table, I am trying to make pairings using following logic:

Subcomponents A, B, C, D make 1 parent component which is Y and subcomponents E,F,G,H make another parent component Z. These pairings can only be made if the difference in value of these 4 components is less than or equal to 3.

For more context on pairing logic, the difference has to be overall for each combination of pair of subcomponents within a parent component, no need for it to be consecutive. The difference in value between any 2 sub components within a parent component cannot be greater than 3.

| Sub component | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 10 |
| C | 12 |
| D | 11 |
| A | 10 |
| A | 15 |
| D | 10 |
| E | 10 |
| F | 12 |
| G | 11 |
| H | 10 |
| F | 15 |
| F | 10 |

The results should looks something like the table below. Every time a parent component is formed through matching, it's count should increase by 1. How do I go about doing this?

| Sub component | Value | Parent part | Parent part count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | A | 1 |
| B | 10 | A | 1 |
| C | 12 | A | 1 |
| D | 11 | A | 1 |
| A | 10 | N/A | N/A |
| A | 15 | N/A | N/A |
| D | 10 | N/A | N/A |
| E | 10 | B | 1 |
| F | 12 | B | 1 |
| G | 11 | B | 1 |
| H | 10 | B | 1 |
| F | 15 | N/A | N/A |
| F | 10 | N/A | N/A |

Comment: The logic is not fully clear. Do you need to have 4 unique items? Not previously used? Contiguous? Regarding the difference of 4, is it for consecutive values? Overall? There are many way to interpret your example, please be as explicit as you can. How would you do it with a pen and paper?

Comment: @mozway, yes need to have 4 unique sub component to make 1 parent component. The difference has to be overall for each combination of pair of subcomponents within a parent component, no need for it to be consecutive. Sorry for not noting these conditions clearly.

Comment: Can you then [edit] the answer adding clear details on the logic? Eventually with more examples

Comment: I have added some more details on the question and happy to help with further clarifications as required.

Comment: You have addressed 1 question, what about the others? ;)